# Passing values into regex match function

Tags: python, regex

In python (it's a Django filter), I'm doing this:

```
lReturn = re.sub(r'\[usecase:([ \w]+)]', r'EXTEND WITH <a href="/usecase/%s/\1/">\1</a>' % pCurrentProjectName, lReturn)
```

I'd like to use a function instead of a string (so I can check that the usercase is a valid name), so it would change to this:

```
def _match_function(matchobj):
    lMatch = matchobj.group(1)
    return "EXTEND WITH <a href='/usecase/%s/%s/'>%s</a>" % (pCurrentProjectName, lMatch, lMatch)

lReturn = re.sub(r'\[usecase:([ \w]+)]', _match_function, lReturn)
```

How do I get pCurrentProjectName into the _match_function() function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a function that returns a function (a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29)):

```
def _match_function(name):
    def f(matchobj):
        lMatch = matchobj.group(1)
        return "EXTEND WITH <a href='/usecase/%s/%s/'>%s</a>" % (name, lMatch, lMatch)
    return f

lReturn = re.sub(r'\[usecase:([ \w]+)]', _match_function(pCurrentProjectName), lReturn)
```